# htaccess, a code doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my htaccess code. I work on it for days but can't fix it.

Site post url: `/index.php?a=post&m=37`

What I want: `/post/37`

my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=post&m=$1 [L]
```

This is working: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L]`

But when I put this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=post&m=$1 [L]` I'm getting "Internal Server Error" in all pages of site. What's the solution? :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same pattern `(.*)` cannot be routed to 2 different targets.

You probably meant this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?a=post&m=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to chance url to `/post/` so now it works thanks anubhava but now topbar notifications doesn't work...

Comment: I have no idea what is `topbar notification` in terms of rewrite rule